# networking service preventing wpa_supplicant to connect

Tags: raspbian, wpa-supplicant

I have two raspberry 3B running raspbian jessie. On both, I try to connect to the same wifi network using the following commands:

```
sudo wpa_passphrase "test" "abcd1234" > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
sudo wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

On computer A, it works smoothly.
On computer B, it doesn't work and prints me the following error:

```
4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
```

Stopping the `networking` service on computer B solves the problem but:

- it is running on computer A without problem
- I have no idea why this works and I fear collateral damages.

Would you folks have any idea on what's going on ?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's not `pre-shared key may be incorrect`, it **is** incorrect.
I'm not sure why it works on rasp "A", probably because wpa_supplicant.conf already contains info on network, or another configuration file is being used, whatever the reason. 4 digit password is just not valid for WPA PSK, wpa_passphrase won't allow it.

```
cs-server@csserver-HP-EliteDesk-800-G2-SFF:/$ wpa_passphrase "test" "1234"
Passphrase must be 8..63 characters
cs-server@csserver-HP-EliteDesk-800-G2-SFF:/$ wpa_passphrase "test" "12345678"
network={
    ssid="test"
    #psk="12345678"
    psk=fe727aa8b64ac9b3f54c72432da14faed933ea511ecab15bbc6c52e7522f709a
}
cs-server@csserver-HP-EliteDesk-800-G2-SFF:/$
```

You are basically redirecting `"Passphrase must be 8..63 characters"` to your config file.
Also, I'm not sure if you really want to use ">" for redirection. You overwrite your .conf file completely, deleting even juicy details. Without going into deep details since it's offtopic, I might imagine you would like to have at least those settings at the top of your .conf file.

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
ap_scan=1
```

Comment: well, that's wat I get for not putting the real psk :) I'll update my question to reflect the reality sorry